# Existence of loops in Statistical field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

Since the quantum mechanical formulation of statistical mechanics in canonical ensemble has the terms equivalent to cluster expansion (which can be conveniently written in terms of diagrams similar to Feynman diagrams. is there a possibility of loops in statistical physics. and also how does renormalization come in the picture in statistical physics.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad questions here, thus I'll give a minimal answer. If you want more details, you can look at the references. I can also indicate some textbook references if needed.

> is there a possibility of loops in statistical physics

Actually there is, within the framework of Statistical Field Theory. This is mainly use to study critical dynamics, see for example the treatment of Ginzburg Landau theory.

> how does renormalization come in the picture in statistical physics

Renormalization comes in same way as in QFT, but it should be noted that the technical difficulties differ.

For references, see, for example:

- [this article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.12.4945) by De Dominicis & al.
- 'Critical dynamics of ferromagnets in 6-e dimensions: General discussion and detailed calculation' by Ma & Mazenko

(if i find a publicly available link for the 2nd article I'll edit)